# How to look up IPFS url in Ethereum Bytecode meta data

Tags: solidity, ipfs, bytecode, deployed-bytecode

I have a solidity contract that is deployed on the Ethereum mainnet. The contract's bytecode ended with (what I assume to be) an IPFS url

`{ipfs}64736f6c634300060c0033`

How do I look up this URL on ipfs? It doesn't seem to be in the correct format currently to be searchable